# IntelliJ No files were downloaded for xyz

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jira

I've created a new project in IntelliJ.
When I go in to:
Project Structure -> Libraries -> Add -> From Maven -> 'com.atlassian.seraph:atlassian-seraph:3.0.3'
I get the error message 'No files were downloaded for com.atlassian.seraph:atlassian-seraph:3.0.3'

**Backstory:**
I'm using IntelliJ to write a custom SSO authenticator for JIRA. This is not a JIRA plugin, it's just a class that a custom JSP will use.

I intend to produce a JAR and put it in WEB-INF/lib.

I'm not sure what I've missed here. This is my first exposure to maven and I've googled this extensively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you did not change the default remote repository of your maven, it [should be this](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) . It seems that the artifact (com.atlassian.seraph:atlassian-seraph:3.0.3), you are looking for, is not in the default remote repository. There are two solutions for your case,

1.Add a new remote repository, which has this artifact, to your project.

2.Find the jar file somewhere on internet, add it to your project as an external jar file. [Here](https://softwarecave.org/2014/06/14/adding-external-jars-into-maven-project/) is a great tutorial about this.

Comment: Thanks @bernhard I've moved on to other projects for the moment but as soon as I can get back to this I'll try it and accept it if it works

Comment: Thanks @bernhard, I got it working with solution #1. Sorry it took so long to accept, but I've only just gotten back to this project!

Answer (score 0):

I've changed from idea 14 to idea 15, and downloading maven jar feature started to work)

My Maven setup in ide aimed to external v3.2.1, but may be it would work even with bundled one.